# Get value from array in unity: debug works, value's changing, but color not changing

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, unity-game-engine, contains

I want to call some values in array from mysql through a UI-Button. If the array contains strings equal to button's name, the button will pick values from the array. This value ( 0 & 1) will be translated into slider's value which is child of the button and it will change its color accordingly. if the slider value = 1, button color = green, if 0 = red.

The problem is i couldn't change the button color. Changing the value works, debug works too. This should be very simple, but i don't know why it doesn't work. This is the script attached in the button:

```
public string[] data;

void Start () { 
        StartCoroutine (loadStart ());
    }

    public IEnumerator loadStart (){
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

        WWW sliderData = new WWW ("localhost/unitypb/slider.php");
        //wait until download finish
        yield return sliderData;

        //get data as text
        string sliderString = sliderData.text;
        //print (verantString);
        data = sliderString.Split (';');

        foreach (string x in data) {
            if (x.Contains (this.gameObject.name + "-KW" + KWtext.text)) {
                int index = Array.IndexOf (data, x);

                int savedValue = Convert.ToInt32 (GetDataValue (data [index], "Value:"));
                this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value = savedValue;

                if (this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value == 1) {
                    this.GetComponent <Image> ().color = Color.green;
                }

                if (this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value == 0) {
                    this.GetComponent <Image> ().color = Color.red;
                }

                Debug.Log (Convert.ToString (this.gameObject.name + "-KW" + KWtext.text));
            } else if (!x.Contains (this.gameObject.name + "-KW" + KWtext.text)) {
                            this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value = 0;
                this.GetComponent <Image> ().color = Color.white;
                Debug.Log ("not available");
            } 
        }
    }

public string GetDataValue (string data, string index) {
        string value = data.Substring (data.IndexOf(index)+index.Length);
        if(value.Contains("|")) 
            value = value.Remove (value.IndexOf ("|"));
        return value;
    }
```

However, if I remove this line the script would run just fine. But I would need it for other similar functions so i can't remove it.

```
else if (!x.Contains (this.gameObject.name + "-KW" + KWtext.text)) {
                                this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value = 0;
                    this.GetComponent <Image> ().color = Color.white;
                    Debug.Log ("not available");
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on feedback from Ramazan I made slight change in my script and so far it works fine. this might help someone:

```
public IEnumerator loadStart (){
    //yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

    WWW sliderData = new WWW ("localhost/unitypb/slider.php");
    //wait until download finish
    yield return sliderData;

    //get data as text
    string sliderString = sliderData.text;
    //print (verantString);
    data = sliderString.Split (';');

    this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value = 0;
    this.GetComponent <Image> ().color = Color.white;

    foreach (string x in data) {
        if (x.Contains (this.gameObject.name + "-KW" + KWtext.text)) {
            int index = Array.IndexOf (data, x);

            //float svalue = this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value;
            //int isvalue = (int)svalue;
            int savedValue = Convert.ToInt32 (GetDataValue (data [index], "Value:"));
            this.GetComponentInChildren <Slider> ().value = savedValue;

            if (savedValue == 1) {
                this.GetComponent <Image> ().color = Color.green;
            }

            if (savedValue == 0) {
                this.GetComponent <Image> ().color = Color.red;
            }

            Debug.Log (Convert.ToString (this.gameObject.name + "-KW" + KWtext.text));

        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache that Image and Slider components for clarity. You use them multiple times, and each time you are using GetComponent.

`savedValue` is same as value of the slider, use that instead for comparisons.

> else if (!x.Contains (this.gameObject.name + "-KW" + KWtext.text))

The second if is not required, because when the first if is not true, the second if will be true (unnecessary condition check)

For the problem, if your data array has more than 1 element and with different button names, the second if will be set the color of the button white, because some data element will not contain the button name, and so the second else if condition will be applied to the button.

Comment: thx, I also thought the problem might be caused by the second if, but i dont know why. Now i understand it a little but. The problem is I kinda need the second if for other purposes. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Yes. First, group the data for each buttons. Then, for each group and for each data in the that group apply the if/else color conditions.

Comment: Also, if it suits you, first set colors of all buttons to white. Then, apply the color logic(foreach, without the second if

Comment: Thank Ramazan, i did what you suggested and it worked like charm